# Exibir diretórios e sub-diretórios

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma rotina para ler e exibir arquivos e diretórios em PHP.

Meu problema é para ler diretórios dentro sub-diretórios.

```
<?php
// linux
$dir = new DirectoryIterator( '/www/sistema/fotos/' );
// windows
//$dir = new DirectoryIterator( 'c:/xampp/htdocs/sistema/fotos/' );

// array contendo os diretórios permitidos    
$diretoriosPermitidos = array("albuns");

foreach($dir as $file)
{
    // verifica se $file é diferente de '.' ou '..'
    if (!$file->isDot())
    {
        // listando somente os diretórios
        if  ( $file->isDir() )
        {
            // atribui o nome do diretório a variável
            $dirName = $file->getFilename();

            // listando somente o diretório permitido
            if( in_array($dirName, $diretoriosPermitidos)) {
                // subdiretórios
                $caminho = $file->getPathname();
                // chamada da função de recursividade
                recursivo($caminho, $dirName);
            }
        }

        // listando somente os arquivos do diretório
        if  ( $file->isFile() )
        {
            // atribui o nome do arquivo a variável
            $fileName = $file->getFilename();
            //
            echo "fotos: ".$fileName."<br>";
        }
    }
}

function recursivo( $caminho, $dirName ){

    global $dirName;

    $DI = new DirectoryIterator( $caminho );

    foreach ($DI as $file){
        if (!$file->isDot())
        {
            if  ( $file->isFile() )
            {
                //
                $fileName = $file->getFilename();
                //
                echo $dirName.": ".$fileName."<br>";
            }
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Nem tentei ler o código, porque não entendi de fato qual seria o "problema", mas já tentou utilizar o `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`? E será que realmente precisa utilizar esses iteradores para isso?

Comment: Vou ler a documentação do RecursiveDirectoryIterator e volto para dizer se deu certo. Obrigado!